# Push, pop and display functions from one string to a stack

Tags: c, string, stack

I'm trying to write a program where the user introduces an array numbers and alphabethic characters. Then the program reads the array, if he sees a number, the program should push that number into one stack. However, if he sees an alphabetical character, the last number pushed is popped.

So far I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 20

int top, i;
void push (double stack[], double x, int top)
{
stack[top] = x;
}
 int pop (double stack[])
{
    double x;
    stack [top]=x;
    return x;
}

void display (double stack[],int top)
{
    int i;
    printf ("\n The stack is: ");
        for (i=0; i<=top; i++)
         {
           printf ("%lf\n",stack[i]);
     }
}

void main()
{
int r;
int stack[10];
char array[10];
printf("introduce the numbers");
fgets(array,MAX,stdin);
int l;
r=strlen(array);
top=0;
for (l=0;l<=r;l++)
{
int n;
if (isdigit(array[l]))
 {
    push(stack,array[l],top);
    top=top+1;
 }

 if (islower(array[l]))
 {
        pop(stack);
        printf("you have popped %d", n);
        top=top-1;
 }
}
 display(stack,top);
}
```

For some reason the program does not work, if I introduce `22a` the output is:
`you have popped 4194432
The stack is: 50.00000
50.00000`

I am particularly interested in how should I write the pop,push and display to make this program work. How can I do it?

Comment: You're reading twenty characters `#define MAX 20` into an array of size 10. Also, in your loop you have `for(l=0; l<=r; l++)`, which may result in a segfault when you'll try to access `stack[l]` if `l==r`.

Comment: What's more, you're calling `pop(stack)` and _not using the return value_ (!), so what makes you think that an uninitialized variable `n` will contain some useful value?

Comment: Whenever you're looping, you do `for(i=0; i<=threshold; i++)`, which doesn't make sense: you're trying to get `treshold + 1` values from the array, while you definitely want only `treshold` of them.

Comment: When popping, you should decrement top first, otherwise you will not access the previously pushed element.

Answer (score 3):

First off, your variable `n`, the value of which you're printing, is *uninitialized* and contains whatever garbage that was in the memory at the moment of its creation.

Also, why are you printing it? I think you meant to say `n = pop(stack);`, right? Otherwise this printing is useless.

Throughout your code you're writing loops the wrong way: `for (t=0; t<=threshold; t++)`. This code will make the loop run `threshold + 1` times, but you obviously want only `threshold`, so do `for (t=0; t<threshold; t++)` instead.

You're also reading (`fgets(array,MAX,stdin);`) *maximum twenty* characters into your `array`, which can hold only ten characters.

To use `strlen` on an array, you need it to end with zero (null-terminator). In your code `array` is not necessarily initialized with zeros, so use `memset(array, 0, 10);` before using `array`:

1. [Docs on `memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)
2. [Tutorial on `for` loops](https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-for-loop-while-loop-break-and-continue)
3. [`void main()` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)
4. [What to read to learn C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)